# AngularJS Controller as service or service as controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

While creating dashboard application I came to situation where I need to have both `AngularJS` controller and service in one.

At main (1st) page I have `mainController` (nothing with layout) and also `layoutController` which is binded to the buttons with methods `loadLayoutFromAPI()` and `saveLayoutToAPI()`.

Now, at secondary (2nd) there is `secondController` only and not `layoutController`. I need to use methods from the `layoutController` directly from `secondController` and I prefer not to insert `ng-controller` directive inside the HTML (instead put it to `secondController` through dependency-injection like service).

MainPage (1st):

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <!-- some other code -->

    <div ng-controller="layoutController as ctrl">
        <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.loadLayoutFromAPI()">Load</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.saveLayoutToAPI()">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

SecondaryPage (2nd):

```
<div ng-controller="secondController">
    <!-- some other code -->
</div>
```

I tried to look for this issue, but no answers found at all.

**Question:** How should I use same piece of code (methods `save()` and `load()`) once as a Controller (`ng-controller`) and other time as a service (included via `dependency-injection`)?

Thanks

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hedapaqome/3/edit?html,js,console,output) as requested

Comment: Create a repro in jsbin or plnkr]

Comment: Also, don't use methods from other controllers directly from other controllers... this is why services are there. Controllers are only there to engage with the view!

Comment: @CallumLinington Added JSBin in Q, I agree with You on that principe (ctrl for View, service for code-behind), but how should I avoid writting same code twice? I got an idea about using `layoutService` and then creating `layoutController` as a Wrapper, which would call the service methods. Is it suitable?

Comment: Something like this: https://jsbin.com/yusatisafe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @CallumLinington Yes, this is exactly what I mean, but is it the best approach? Isn't there any other workaround? (I feel this is too complicated, imagine having 50 methods and wrapping them all)

Comment: a work around, is a phrase given to trying to circumvent an issue. But there is no issue here. If you want to communicate between controllers, or directives or anything else that is what services, factories and providers are for. When building any application, you always abstract out common functionality to some kind of service

Comment: Creating service is the best solution , however you can also use broadcast and emit to communicate with controllers

Comment: @CallumLinington you definitely should make an answer :)

Comment: @VaibhavShah Only problem with events is that they don't scale (in terms of maintainability but also can cause some perf issues if you just arbitrarily start firing off tonnes.) and can get very difficult to manage! Services allow you to get better control on what is going on

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks for the time mate, nice expl. & answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use methods from other controllers directly from other controllers... this is why services are there. Controllers are only there to engage with the view!

If you want to communicate between controllers, or directives or anything else that is what services, factories and providers are for. When building any application, you always abstract out common functionality to some kind of service

For example:

```
//Just an APP def
var app = angular.module('dashApp', []);

//LayoutController
app
  .controller('layoutController', ['CtrlService', function(ctrlService){
  this.saveLayoutToAPI = function(){
    ctrlService.save();
  }
  this.loadLayoutFromAPI = function(){
    ctrlService.load();
  }
}]);

//Main Controller
app
  .controller('mainController', function(){
  //no work with layout at all
});

//Secondary controller

app
  .controller('secondController', ['CtrlService', function(ctrlService){
  this.save = function(){
     ctrlService.save();
  }
  this.load = function(){
     ctrlService.load();
  }
}]);

app
  .service('CtrlService', function () {  

    var obj = {
      save: function () {
        console.log('Layout saved.');
      },
      load: function () {
        console.log('Layout loaded.');
      }
    }

    this.save = obj.save;
    this.load = obj.load;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $broadcast to achieve this.

Below is the diagram explaining the concept.

[image]

Sample code in controller-2

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('saveCalled');
```

Sample code in controller-1

```
 $scope.$on('saveCalled',function(){
       saveLayoutToApi();
    })
```

Comment: As was stated before (comments under question), this solution would work, however it might get crispy once we get to talk about performance and maintaining all the listeners etc. Thanks for the answer